# Send Facebook Request from Server?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-requests

I want to add a feature that makes users can invite their friends to use the app (iOS and Android native app), and it's already there with Facebook's [Request Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/).

My problem is that most of my users are from China where Facebook has been blocked, so the request dialog couldn't be open. I am wondering if there is a way that can send facebook request via server, so that the request can be sent within China and without bypassing the GFW?

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the user's Facebook token once they are logged in then you can use this from your server to exercise any of the permissions the token allows. However you'll face the same problem for the user to authenticate with Facebook in the first place and get the token.

However, it has been reported that many Chinese users know how to bypass the GFW and set it up themselves. For these users you shouldn't have any problem and these are the users that will actually have Facebook friends to invite.

You could also consider integrating to the Chinese social networks as many of your Chinese users may have friends on those networks to invite.

Comment: Thx for your respond! I do included other social networks in my app, Facebook is one of them.Yep that most of active Facebook users in China knows how to bypass the GFW, but most of Facebook users in China gave up using Facebook as it's not easy to bypass the GFW. What I want to discuss is not the wall but the method. :)